# java.awt.headless issue

Tags: java, jvm, awt

While running tests test runner hangs up on next code

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x097f4c00 nid=0x7d6a runnable [0xb7693000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$100(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:52)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:155)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:131)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:68)
    - locked <0xae3d8da8> (a java.lang.Class for java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:89)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:834)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:826)
    - locked <0xae3e60e0> (a java.lang.Class for java.awt.Toolkit)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:807)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1333)
    ... buisiness code trying to do something in EDT
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.runChild(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:246)
    at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:39)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:420)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:911)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:743)
```

Found -Djava.awt.headless=true could help. After restarting tests I've got exception

```
12-01-2012 05:04:23,369 [main] ERROR {} java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:998)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1320)
    ...
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.runChild(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:246)
    at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:39)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:420)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:911)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:743)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:432)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:202)
    ...
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Intestingly, previuos code that hangs up passed successfully and tests failed later while trying to construct some GUI.
This for sure is related to DISPLAY [link1](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=d0f56a410f07cffffffff931dbecb783a1f8?bug_id=4979996), [link2](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5032424).
I'm running tests on Linux machine with real configured display.

Any idea what causes issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwingUtilities.invokeLater only makes sense for a GUI application.

I avoid any Swing libraries in non GUI components and I would use an ExecutorService instead.

Comment: both issues happens with same test that creates and manipulates GUI. Why in first code SwingUtilities.invokeLater is no ready to work?

Comment: Because you set `java.awt.headless=true` This turns off GUI features which I would assume includes not running the EDT meaning you can't pass anything to it to run in that thread.

Comment: It is clear for me about headless=true. Not clear why DISPLAY is not ready in first case. When is the timestamp it is safe to use it?

Comment: Which timestamp are you referring to?

Comment: Just want to figure out from when it is safe to use invokeLater

Comment: I think you have determined its not safe to use in unit tests.